# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos(x)\ln(\cos(x))}-\sqrt{1+\ln(\cos(x))}}{\sqrt[3]{\tan x}-\sqrt[3]{\sin x}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sin^2x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

would someone please help me out with this limit? It should probably be rewritten as an expression with known limits mostly, but I don't really know where to begin.

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos \left(x\right)\cdot \ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)}-\sqrt{1+\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)}}{\sqrt[3]{\tan \left(x\right)}-\sqrt[3]{\sin \left(x\right)}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sin ^2\left(x\right)}$$

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Let me suggest you take a look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [avoiding "I don't really know where to begin" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Your post is a bare problem statement, which can quickly attract down votes and close votes. I suggest editing your post saying *something* about what you might have tried on this question, as suggested in those links.

Comment: L'Hopital's rule, and lots of messy algebra

Comment: you should start with substituting tan(x) or cos(x). those trig functions get in the way

Comment: i substituted u=cosx and found that the limit is 3/4

Comment: I agree with @MichaelHartley.  I would start by applying L'Hospital's rule.  Subsitution may also be helpful to limit the messy algebra for awhile.

Comment: Use conjugate, L'H only makes it more messier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{gathered}
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\sqrt {1 + \cos \left( x \right)\ln \left( {\cos \left( x \right)} \right)}  - \sqrt {1 + \ln \left( {\cos \left( x \right)} \right)} }}{{\sqrt[3]{{\tan \left( x \right)}} - \sqrt[3]{{\sin \left( x \right)}}}}.\frac{{\sqrt[3]{x}}}{{{{\sin }^2}\left( x \right)}} \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}{2}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\ln \left( {\cos \left( x \right)} \right)\left( {\cos \left( x \right) - 1} \right)}}{{\sqrt[3]{{\tan \left( x \right)}} - \sqrt[3]{{\sin \left( x \right)}}}}.\frac{{\sqrt[3]{x}}}{{{{\sin }^2}\left( x \right)}} \hfill \\
   =  - \frac{1}{4}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\ln \left( {1 - {{\sin }^2}\left( x \right)} \right)}}{{{{\sin }^2}\left( x \right)}}.\frac{{\left( {1 - \cos \left( x \right)} \right)}}{{{x^2}}}.\frac{{{x^2}\sqrt[3]{x}}}{{\sqrt[3]{{\tan \left( x \right)}} - \sqrt[3]{{\sin \left( x \right)}}}} \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}{8}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{{x^2}\sqrt[3]{x}}}{{\sqrt[3]{{\tan \left( x \right)}} - \sqrt[3]{{\sin \left( x \right)}}}} = \frac{1}{8}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\sqrt[3]{x}}}{{\sqrt[3]{{\tan \left( x \right)}}}}.\frac{{{x^2}}}{{\left( {1 - \sqrt[3]{{\cos \left( x \right)}}} \right)}} \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}{8}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{{x^2}\left( {1 + \sqrt[3]{{\cos \left( x \right)}} + \sqrt[3]{{{{\cos }^2}\left( x \right)}}} \right)}}{{\left( {1 - \cos \left( x \right)} \right)}} = \frac{1}{8}.2.3 = \frac{3}{4} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}